# Statistical test on dataset containing percentage data that do not add up to 100%

Tags: python, chi-squared-test, percentage

I am trying to test for significance on a set of counts. In a normal scenario, I could use a chi-square test to test each condition, however, I have an issue that the percentages do not add up to 100. My real problem actually comes from baseball data that I am analyzing from a motor control perspective. I am trying to make the argument that certain variables cannot account for significant changes in homerun percentage, specifically, different pitch parameters (type of pitch, velocity, movement, etc.).

For clarity, I will simplify the question with a more general toy problem. A common example for chi-square is where you have two classes and are counting the number of instances of each grade.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class 1 | 20 | 32 | 15 |
| Class 2 | 24 | 28 | 16 |

In the case above, I can use chi-squared to compare class A to class B. However, what if I had a bunch of classes and I only wanted to compare based on the # of A's. Furthermore, each year the class is a different size.

|  | **A** | B | C | # Students |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class 1 | **20** | 32 | 15 | 67 |
| Class 2 | **24** | 28 | 16 | 68 |
| Class 3 | **18** | 32 | 12 | 62 |
| Class 4 | **21** | 35 | 15 | 71 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Class N | **25** | 30 | 14 | 69 |

It doesn't have to be this way, but it could also be represented as % data since the classes are different sizes each year:

|  | **A** | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class 1 | **0.30** | 0.48 | 0.22 |
| Class 2 | **0.35** | 0.41 | 0.24 |
| Class 3 | **0.29** | 0.51 | 0.19 |
| Class 4 | **0.30** | 0.49 | 0.21 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Class N | **0.36** | 0.43 | 0.20 |

**NOTE: These are all made up numbers and are just to explain the problem.**

So my question then is how can I compare these A's since they all come from different class sizes? Chi-square seems wrong and I assume that I cannot simply use a t-test for this problem since the data are not normally distributed and are a bit more uniform with some slight variations (also there is a small number of groups, or classes as in above). One solution that has been proposed to me by a friend is to use Bayes factors to determine if certain values (classes in the above example) deviate from the overall average. I.e., making the case for each class being represented by individual %'s vs the classes having values near the overall group mean.

A second component to this question is more specifically related to the baseball problem. Let's say that I want to consider the relationship between velocity and homerun %. As opposed to pitch types, which is naturally discrete (analogous to class number above), velocity can be treated as continuous. The velocity can be binned and analyzed in the same manner or perhaps a different approach exists.

BTW, all of my analysis is currently in python.

Thanks!

Comment: What you call percents are better called proportions or fractions. EIther way, a chi-square test requires counted frequencies. You could test A versus not A using a chi-square test on the corresponding frequencies.  Your second question on velocity and homeruns is better asked separately.

Comment: Great, thanks @NickCox for the clarification. Just to be clear, do you mean something like this:    A versus notA where (A + notA) = Total;   A = [A1, A2, A3, .... ];  notA = [ (Total1 - A1), (Total2 - A2), (Total3 - A3), ... ],
where A and notA are counts? Or should they be proportions, such as A1/Total1 and (Total1 - A1)/Total1?

Then perform the chi-square on A vs notA?

Comment: They must be counts -- as you describe.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure of your objective. Maybe, as @NickCox
suggests, you're looking at 'A' vs. 'non A' for several
classes (five below). Suppose you want to know if the proportion of 'A' is different in different groups.
(Notice my one change from the fictitious counts
in your Question, in quest of a more interesting example.)

```
Class    1   2   3   4   5
--------------------------
   A    24  17  21  27  34
 Non    43  51  61  44  30
--------------------------
Total   67  68  82  71  64

a  =  c(24,17,21,27,34)
tot = c(67,68,82,71,64)
non = tot - a;  non
[1] 43 51 61 44 30
```

Then `prop.test` in R, can test whether there are
statistically significant differences in proportions of A among the five groups. For these data, we reject the
null hypothesis that all proportions are equal, with
P-value is $0.0034 < 0.05 5\%.$

```
prop.test(a, tot)

    5-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  a out of tot
X-squared = 15.726, df = 4, p-value = 0.003409
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4    prop 5 
0.3582090 0.2500000 0.2560976 0.3802817 0.5312500
```

The test above is essentially the same as a chi-squared
test of homogeneity on the contingency table `TAB` below.
The P-value is the same as above for `prop.test`.

```
TAB = rbind(a, non);  TAB
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
a     24   17   21   27   34
non   43   51   61   44   30

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 15.726, df = 4, p-value = 0.003409
```

The chi-squared test compares the observed counts in `TAB` with expected counts found using the null hypothesis (that there are no differences) along with the
row and column totals of `TAB`. The sum of squares of the
Pearson residuals, shown in the table below, is the chi-squared test statistic:

```
chisq.test(TAB)$resid
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
a    0.12153715 -1.387071 -1.429772  0.4397454  2.460629
non -0.08907255  1.016561  1.047856 -0.3222821 -1.803354
```

The Pearson residuals with the largest absolute values
may point the way to useful *ad hoc* tests of the data. (That is, they point the way to important disagreements between observed and expected counts.)

In particular, it may be useful to compare Groups 2 and 5 and Groups 3 and 5. In particular, the second of these
comparisons shows a highly significant difference
at about the 0.1% level.

To avoid 'false discovery'
from repeated analyses of the same data, one should
require lower P-values in order to declare significant differences. How much lower may depend on the number
of *ad hoc* comparisons that are made. The Bonferroni
criterion is to divide 5% by the number of comparisons.
So maybe we should use the 1% or 2% level here.
By this criterion, we can say that Groups 3 and 5
differ significantly.

```
chisq.test(TAB[ , c(3,5)])

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TAB[, c(3, 5)]
X-squared = 10.448, df = 1, p-value = 0.001228
```

*Notes:* (1) Groups 2 and 5 also differ significantly.

```
chisq.test(TAB[ , c(3,5)])$p.val
[1] 0.001227876
```

(2) If you have questions about the above, please leave
a comment. If you have different objectives for such count data, please edit your Question with specifics, and maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I’m struggling with a similar situation here so I’ll share my reasoning in hope we can discuss it further. :)

The general idea is to go for a permutation test over the percentage distribution (I’m not sure if we can frame the problem this way, though).

The idea is to decide which statistic to test upon, e.g, using the mean difference of the percentage distribution - in your case A and not A.

Note that this is different from saying that the mean percentage is such a value, instead, it is the mean of the percentage distribution.

I’m not sure if is there any problem in following this approach. I hope someone can help and provide more details on this.

Once this is possible, one example of permutation test Python (taken from the [Practical Statistics for Data Scientists](https://github.com/gedeck/practical-statistics-for-data-scientists/blob/master/python/code/Chapter%203%20-%20Statistical%20Experiments%20and%20Significance%20Testing.py) book) is:

```
import random

def perm_func(x, nA, nB):
    """A Python version of a permutation test.
    
    This function works by sampling (without replacement) nB indices and assigning
    them to the B group; the remaining nA indices are assigned to group A. The
    difference between the two means is returned.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x: dataframe
        A single data set represented by a dataframe object containing all the samples
    nA: int
        number of samples to resample from group A
    nB: int
        number of samples to resample from group B
    Return
    ------
    float
        The difference between the two means
    """  
    n = nA + nB
    idx_B = set(random.sample(range(n), nB))
    idx_A = set(range(n)) - idx_B

    return x.loc[idx_B].mean() - x.loc[idx_A].mean()
```